# How to edit the self signup page of WSO2-IS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to use the `WSO2-IS` (5.5.0) as Identity Provider for my various applications and enable single sing-on for all of them.
I have added one of my app as `service provider` and configured the Oauth/OpenID Connector it.
Because I want to allow my users to signup by themselves, I have enabled 'Self User Registration' under `Account Management Policies` in Resident Identity Provider.

So When I try to self signup, I receive the sign up page with bunch of form fields which I want to edit.
Here is the screenshot of what I form fields I get:

[image]

How do I edit this page?
For example, If I just want `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Password`, `ConfirmPassword` and `Organization` what are the changes to be made and where?

From the documentation, I figured out that `Claim Configuration` of the Service Provider should do the thing.
I have even tried to configure the claims and tried to use custom claim dialect. But with no luck.

How do I achieve it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes that shows in the self sign up page are the WSO2 dialect claims which has "Supported by Default" configuration enabled. If you o to claim dialect list page and go to "http://wso2.org/claims" dialect and expand agny claim, you can see this configuration. Mandatory one's (which has the red astrix mark) are the claims that has "Required" config enabled. For example see below config of the department claim.

[image]

If you go to one of the user's profile from the management console, you can see the same set of claims there also.

You can change the "Supported by Default" and "Required" config of each claim to cater your requirement in the registration profile.

One other option is you can customize the self sign up page itself. Page is self-registration-with-verification.jsp in accountrecoveryendpoint we application in <IS-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps folder. But still you will have to ask the user to enter the "Required" claims

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to make the `Service Provider` use custom dialect? I mean I don't want to change any default `wso2.org/claims`. I have already defined `tanent/customClaims` [ which has the claim mapping from `wso2.org/claims` ]. How do I configure my Service Provider to use claims from `tanent/customClaims` and not `wso2.org/claims`

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. By design wso2.org claims will be used for internal purposes. Other dialects are for external communications.